# Django conditional annotation without filtering

Tags: python, mysql, django, annotations, conditional-statements

I have a Student model and an Entry model. Each Entry has a foreign key to a Student, a year-stamp, and two numeric values (value1 and value2). I am overriding the get_queryset() method in the StudentAdmin class, and using the Django ORM, I want to annotate a field that we'll call "specialvalue".

Students have at most one Entry for each year, but they might have none, and they might have an Entry for years in the future. The value of "specialvalue" will be equal to Entry__value1 minus Entry__value2 for the Entry for the current year. If the Student has no Entry for the current year, then specialvalue will just be equal to None, and these Students will NOT be removed from the queryset.

How can I do this? At first I tried splitting the queryset into two:

```
queryset_1 = queryset.filter(entry__year=THIS_YEAR).annotate(specialvalue=...)
queryset_2 = queryset.exclude(entry__year=THIS_YEAR).annotate(specialvalue=Value(None))
```

and then annotating them separately and merging them with the | pipe operator, but unfortunately this results in the wrong results due to a [known bug in Django's ORM](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060).

Thank you!

Comment: Add your Student and Entry model structure

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR I think everything relevant is there. Each Entry has a foreignkey to a Student, a year field, and the value1 and value2 fields. Each Student has some irrelevant fields such as name, etc. If there's something else I should include that would help let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think, using Django conditional expression will be applicable solution in your case. Read about Case expression for more information (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case). All you need is to check whether an entry is related to a CURRENT_YEAR or not.

> Case() accepts any number of When() objects as individual arguments. Other options are provided using keyword arguments. If none of the conditions evaluate to TRUE, then the expression given with the default keyword argument is returned. If a default argument isn’t provided, None is used.

I didn't test this solution but I think it should work:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, F, IntegerField
queryset = queryset.annotate(
    specialvalue=Case(
        When(entry__year=THIS_YEAR, 
             then=F('entry__value1') - F('entry__value2')
        ), output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).values_list('specialvalue')
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that before and I just get `TypeError: Cannot call select_related() after .values() or .values_list()`